# How can I make NHibernate Validator use languages other than English?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm, validation

How do I get NHibernate Validator to use a language other than English for its messages? There are several languages included, but I always get my messages in English.

I have tried setting culture, but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the culture?
I guess you need to set both .. culture and UI culture

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
```

Comment: I'm changing the culture through browser language setting. I'm using "de_DE" since de is included in the validator. I'm also checking in the code that the correct culture is set, and both CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture are correct. I just don't understand how to get NHibernate Validator to use the culture. I've checked the validators source code and the tests but I can still not find a way.

Comment: hmm. i am stuck here then too cause it works well for me. Validator should actually pick up the threads culture

Comment: maybe that helps u: http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/create-a-custom-message-interpolator-for-nhibernate-validator.aspx it's the only article i found about i18n with the validator